# MySQL: Count all duplicates and update additional column with acs numbers relative to the duplicated values

Tags: mysql, sql

Slightly complicated question.

I have table below:

```
UserID | Date       |
---------------------
1      | 2015/01/01 |
1      | 2015/01/02 |
1      | 2015/01/03 |
1      | 2015/01/04 |
2      | 2015/01/01 |
2      | 2015/01/02 |
3      | 2015/01/01 |
3      | 2015/01/02 |
3      | 2015/01/03 |
4      | 2015/01/01 |
4      | 2015/01/02 |
4      | 2015/01/03 |
4      | 2015/01/04 |
```

I would like to count all duplicates and then update DupOrder column with numbers representing each duplicated UserID in the same order as date (I hope this make sense).

Here is what I would like to end up with:

```
DupOrder | UserID | Date       |
--------------------------------
1        | 1      | 2015/01/01 |
2        | 1      | 2015/01/02 |
3        | 1      | 2015/01/03 |
4        | 1      | 2015/01/04 |
1        | 2      | 2015/01/01 |
2        | 2      | 2015/01/02 |
1        | 3      | 2015/01/01 |
2        | 3      | 2015/01/02 |
3        | 3      | 2015/01/03 |
1        | 4      | 2015/01/01 |
2        | 4      | 2015/01/02 |
3        | 4      | 2015/01/03 |
4        | 4      | 2015/01/04 |
```

I use mysql.

Comment: In MySQL it can be done with [in-line assignments](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/).

Comment: @user, sorry no attempts as yet.

Comment: @PM 77-1 looks like this might be the answer I was looking for. I need to test it first. Thank you!

Comment: Since MySQL does not support analytical functions, using variables seems like the only choice.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate count, it's the rank within the group.